# How to use await with setTimeout and setInterval?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a function createSession for getting users with returned session object. createSession either returns users or throws string exception. My code is as follow, if session is successfull (which means I have users) continue code.

However I do not know when users are available because other resources also asks for it. So, I want a modify my code that it will try getting users in a timeout, lest say try it every 1 second until timeout 30 seconds reached.

```
async function callTest() {
  const capabilities = {
    type: {
      chrome: 2
    }
  }

  var session = await working.createSession(capabilities)

  if(!session) return
  callTest()

  // remaining code goes here
}
```

I though to use setTimout in a promise but the problem is I can not use await inside a normal function. Can someone help me fixing my code ?

```
var checkAuth = function(capabilities) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {

        var id = setInterval(function() {
           var session = await working.createSession(capabilities)

                if (session) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                    resolve(id);
                }
            });
        }, 10);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use it like this and it should work well

```
var checkAuth = function(capabilities) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setInterval(async function() {
           var session = await working.createSession(capabilities)
                if (session) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                    resolve(id);
                }
           }, 10);
    });
}
```

You should add **async** keyword to function definition in `setInterval`, because `await` can only work in `async` functions.
Update: also move `,10` parameter from `Promise` definition to `setInterval` one

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why it is ok to make that change.

Comment: Functions need to be `async` to be allowed to `await` things.

Comment: your `, 10` argument will be passed to the `new Promise()` constructor. And there should probably be a note about the fact that `setInterval` will not wait for its inner code to finish before triggering again. In this case, a recursive `setTimeout` would probably be better.

Comment: @Kaiido, My fault, but only tested async-await functionality

Comment: "You should add async keyword to function definition in setInterval, because await can only work in async functions. " yet you did not use async in the actual code piece, making you answer not actually make sense. Please edit and clarify.